# MifareClassic not being displayed with getTechList()

Tags: java, android, nfc, mifare

Hello stackoverflow users!

I've been having difficulties in android development working with NFC cards In particular Mifare Classic 4k Cards.

My main problem is that although I know the cards are this technology androids Tag.getTechList() will only return one type of tech for my cards: NfcA.

I am unable to try using the Mifare Classic class as the get() method will return null when used on my Tag object.

This seems to be a difficult and a problem I haven't been able to find any prior questions on. Any help or insight into why android can not detect that my cards are MifareClassic enabled is greatly appreciated.

And if anyone has any insights into using NfcA to access sectors and blocks in Mifare Classic cards, maybe using the transcieve() method that could be a good start.

Right now I have been messing around in attempting to get the ID from the card that is printed on it and I believe should be in one of the first sectors/blocks of the card.

My testing card has a printed ID of 93825

And with the code like so....

```
Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
byte[] uid = tag.getId();
for (byte aTagId : uid) {
            tagInfo += Integer.toHexString(aTagId & 0xFF)+ " ";
        }
for (byte b : uid){
            tagInfo += Integer.toString(b & 0xFF);
        }
```

tagInfo will return a string of: be 50 13 51 190801981
for my card id: 93825
As I said before a line like so

```
MifareClassic mfc = MifareClassic.getTag(tag);
```

will return null even though I am certain the card is of this type. I know because downloading the app from the playstore NFC TagInfo will successfully State that the Tag Type is Mifare Classic 4k.

However a line like

```
NfcA nfca = NfcA.get(tag);
```

will successfully return a NfcA object.

Any input appreciated

Comment: Is NFC TgInfo able to read data from the card? Does NFC TagInfo show the MifareClassic tag technology (o the same Android device)? What Android device are you using?

Comment: Yes it does, thankfully i resolved the issue and figured out i only needed the CSN of the cards which is easy to acquire with tag.getId()

Comment: If NFC TagInfo is able to read *data* (not the UID!) from the card, could you please provide that output then? Also, what Android device are you using?